# react semantic ui render calling function to get output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I need a little help with the following.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?  When I call renderRow from render, I am not getting the output.  Thanks!

```
renderRow() {
  const { Row, Cell } = Table;
  return this.props.registeredAccounts.map(address => {
      return 
        <Row>
          <Cell>{address}</Cell>
          <Cell>minimum payment</Cell>
        </Row>
  })
}

render(){
  const { Header, Row, HeaderCell, Body } = Table;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h3>Registered Accounts</h3>
      <Table>
        <Header>
          <Row>
            <HeaderCell>Address</HeaderCell>
            <HeaderCell>Minimum Payment</HeaderCell>
          </Row>
        </Header>
        <Body>
          {this.renderRow()}
        </Body>
      </Table>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using your `return` on one line. Either wrap your html in parenthesis, or move your `<Row>` tag up to the `return` line. As it is now, you are essentially returning `null`.

```
renderRow() {
  const { Row, Cell } = Table;
  return this.props.registeredAccounts.map(address => {
      return (
        <Row>
          <Cell>{address}</Cell>
          <Cell>minimum payment</Cell>
        </Row>
      )
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought i tried the ().  Tried it again and it work!  Figured it was something stupid.